# Do we get the same answer at any time if we measure a system's energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, eigenvalue, observables

Schrödinger's equation says that the only allowed energy states of a system are the eigenvalues of the energy operator $H$.

1. This means that if we measure the energy of the system at any time we will get the same answer?
2. If not, why?

All I can found so far is that the eigenvalues are measured with certainty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left| #1 \right>}$If 
your state is in an eigenstate of the energy operator then the answer is that you'll get the same value for the energy every time you measure the particle's energy. That is the reason why the energy eigenstates are also called stationary states.

On the other hand you can also have a superposition of energy eigenstates. Assume that $\ket {E_i}$ are energy eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian such that

$$H\ket{E_i} = E_i \ket {E_i}$$

A general state will be in a superposition of the energy eigenstates ie

$$\ket \psi = \sum_i a_i \ket{E_i} \quad \text{with} \quad \sum_i |a_i|^2 =1 $$

Assume that you have a lot of copies of the state $\ket \psi$. Then each time you measure you'll get $|a_i|^2$ of the time the energy eigenstate $\ket{E_i}$. In other words the probability that you'll get the state $\ket{E_i}$ is $|a_i|^2$. Notice however that after the measurement you'll lost all the information about the state $\ket \psi$ because of the collapse of the wave function into an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian. For more information about the collapse of the wave function seethe [measurement problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_problem).

Comment: This means that after the first measurement I will measure from the next time on the same number? An eigenvalue of H?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: And then, how should I find the energy of a system? Or the most probable energy of a system? I cannot measure it many times to find those $a_i$.

Comment: You need to give my the hamiltonian and the initial state. It depends on the system.

Comment: Suppose I have a quantum harmonic oscilator. And I want to find out it's state, or wave function? Is this possible?

Comment: Of course it is possible but that is a whole other story. If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not quite correct. The Schrödinger equivalence says that **if** the system has a definite energy, then this energy can only be an eigenvalue of the system's hamiltonian $\hat H$. There is no requirement, however, for the system to have a definite energy; if the energy is undefined then an energy measurement may return different (eigen)values on different trials.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\lvert #1 \rangle}$The Schrödinger equation does not say what you claim it does.

The time-independent Schrödinger equation is an eigenvalue equation for the Hamiltonian operator
$$ H \ket{\psi_E} = E \ket{\psi_E}$$
where solving for $\ket{\psi_E}$ for a concrete $H$ gives us the occuring eigenstates of $H$. It does *not* say that these are the only allowed states of the system, but that these are the eigenstates of $H$, usually a countable set of states $\ket{\psi_n}$ with eigenvalues $E_n$. Since the time-dependent Schrödinger equation tells us that *any* states evolves in time according to
$$ \mathrm{i}\partial_t\ket{\psi(t)} = H\ket{\psi(t)}$$
the eigenstates evolve particularly simple: For time-independent Hamiltonians: $$\ket{\psi_n(t)} = \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}E_nt}\ket{\psi_n(0)}$$
Now, by the spectral theorem, and ignoring some technicalities, every state is a superposition of these eigenstates, i.e. any $\ket{\psi}$ may be written as a (possibly infinite) sum
$$ \sum_n a_n\ket{\psi_n}$$
where, if the state is normalized, i.e. $\sum_n \lvert a_n \rvert^2 = 1$, the probability to measure $E_n$ for the system is given by $\lvert a_n \rvert^2$ by the Born rule.

Thus, if the system is not in an energy eigenstate, then the measurement result *of the same state* may result in different energies. However, an energy measurement "collapses" the system into an energy eigenstate, so if nothing else interacts with the system after the measurement, subsequent energy measurements of the same system will yield the same energy value with certainty.

Comment: Nearly identical to my answer :).

Comment: "It does not say that these are the only allowed states of the system". If so why the energy states are quantified?

Comment: @SebiSebi: I don't understand your question. They are a *basis* for the space of states, but e.g. $0.5\ket{\psi_0}+0.5\ket{\psi_1}$ is certainly not an eigenstate.

Comment: My question was: "Then why the system can have only discrete energy values?"

Comment: @SebiSebi: Because what you *measure* (with a certain probability) are the eigenvalues, they are the allowed measurement results. You should *not* think of the system having only discrete energy values, though - if the system is not in an eigenstate, it *does not have* a definite energy.